# How do I redirect ALL my protocol-relative URLs to https:// urls?

Tags: wordpress, https, redirect, http-status-code-301

I just set up my Wordpress domain to have an SSL certificate. It's working fine within the site, but if I'm coming from anywhere outside of my own website with anything other than https:// at the beginning, I just wind up on my homepage.

For example, if I enter mysite.ca/about I am taken to mysite.ca.

I have placed this code in my. htaccess file

`RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

But all it seems to do is direct http or protocol-relative urls to the homepage.

(my domain is andrewkurjata.ca, if it helps)

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Using a plugin such as [WordPress Force HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-https/) worked for me in a similar situation.

Comment: I agree with this. The one I've used is Really Simple SSL https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it.

Comment: would you recommend using this in addition to the existing code or in place of it?

Comment: replace it with new one